# Connection form of a Surface of Revolution

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider M, a surface of revolution parametrized by $\phi(u,v)=(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u))$ where $(f(u), g(u))$ would be unit length if considered in the $(y,z)$ plane.

I would like to compute the Christoffel Symbols with respect to $(u,v)$ (and Riemannian metric $\nabla$).

1 - The Riemannian metric induced on the domain of $u,v$ is $(u,v)=du\otimes du+f(u)^2dv\otimes dv$.

2 - So I took an orthonormal basis $e_1=\partial_u$ and $e_2=\frac{1}{f(u)}\partial_v$ and then the dual forms $\theta^1=du$ and $\theta^2=f(u)dv$.

3 - I then computed
$d\theta^1=0$ and $d\theta^2=f^\prime(u)dudv$.

4 - Taking $\omega_1^2=\alpha_udu+\alpha_vdv$ where $\alpha_u,\alpha_v\in C^\infty(M)$ I solved for $\alpha_u,\alpha_v$, using the structural equation $d\theta=\omega\wedge\theta$ (knowing that $\omega^2_1=-\omega^1_2$ and $\omega_i^i=0$ for $i=1,2$, I obtained $\alpha_v=0$ and $\alpha_u=f^\prime(u)$.

So the connection form I obtained is $\omega_1^2=f^\prime(u)du$

Clearly this is incorrect, where is my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: The connection form is definitely *not* correct. Why don't you edit your post to show the details of your computation? Your coframe $\theta^1,\theta^2$ are correct.

Comment: added more details! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d\theta^2 = f’(u)du\wedge dv = \omega_1^2\wedge\theta^1$ tells us that $\omega_1^2 = -f’(u)dv \pmod{du}$ and, indeed, $d\theta^1=0=-\omega_1^2\wedge\theta^2$ tells us that the $du$ coefficient of $\omega_1^2$ is $0$.