Dual basis to tangent space of surface of revolution
I'm trying to derive the geodesic equations for the surface of revolution from this question by solving for the connection forms from the first structural equation and then using this to get the Christoffel symbols of the Riemannian connection $\nabla$ with respect to and deriving the geodesic equations. The surface is given by
$
\psi(u,v)= (f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u)),
$
$0 < v < 2\pi.$
I found an orthonormal basis for the tangent space given by $e_1,e_2$ by normalizing $\partial/\partial u$ and $\partial/\partial v$:
$$
e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{f'(u)^2 + g'(u)^2}}(f'(u)\cos v\, \partial/\partial x + f'(u)\sin v\, \partial/\partial y + g'(u)\, \partial/\partial z),
$$
$$
e_2 = -\sin v\, \partial / \partial x + \cos v\, \partial / \partial y.
$$
I'm now a bit stuck trying to find the dual frame. I think I am looking for $\theta^1$ and $\theta^2$ so that $\theta^1(e_1)=1$, $\theta^1(e_2)=0$, $\theta^2(e_1)=0$, and $\theta^2(e_2)=1$. Writing $\theta^1 = a\, dx + b\, dy + c\, dz,$ I've determined $b = a\tan v$ and ended up with
$$
\sqrt{f'(u)^2 + g'(u)^2} = \frac{af'(u)}{\cos v} + cg'(u),
$$
but I'm a bit unsure where to go from here. Please advise.

Yes, this is indeed the wrong approach. You're working with differential forms defined on the surface, not in $\Bbb R^3$, and so everything should be done in terms of $du$ and $dv$. I find it more useful to look at the induced metric:
$$\psi^*(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) = (f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2)du^2 + f(u)^2\,dv^2.$$
So an orthonormal coframe will be
$$\theta^1 = \sqrt{f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2}du\,, \quad \theta^2 = f(u)\,dv.$$
You might find it helpful to look at Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile, or at a relatively new book on geometry with moving frames, Jeanne Clelland's From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames.

Thank you, this does seem more reasonable. The coefficients of $du$ and $dv$ to me make sense as just to even out the $e_1=\frac{\partial/\partial u}{\lVert\partial/\partial u\rVert} = \frac{\partial/\partial u}{\sqrt{f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2}}$ and $e_2=\frac{\partial/\partial v}{\lVert\partial/\partial v\rVert}=\frac{\partial/\partial v}{f(u)}$. I'll need to read up on how that relates to the induced metric to make sense of how you derived it from that.

or should it be $\theta^2=\lVert f(u)\rVert, dv$?

You mean $|f|$? It is traditional to take $f>0$ to make sure the surface is smooth.

Yes that’s what I meant, and thanks that makes sense!

Writing the connection form $\omega_2^1 = a, du + b, dv$, The first structural equation then tells us that $0 = d\theta^1 = -\omega_2^1\wedge\theta^2$ so $a=0$ as you had indicated in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4794143/111520, but then we also have that $d\theta^2 = \omega_2^1\wedge\theta^1$, so $f'(u) du\wedge dv = b, dv\wedge \sqrt{f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2}, du$, so doesn't this tell us that $b = -\frac{f'(u)}{\sqrt{f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2}}$?

Ah unit speed explains it!
